# Proving these series equations to be equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I was recently attempting to prove the formulae which calculate the sum of arithmetic sequences where the difference between each term is just 1.

I arrived at this formula first, which calculates the sum of the series from 1 to $n$, and then takes away values between 1 and $a$ - the starting term.

$\sum\limits_{a}^n r = \frac{(n+1)(n)}{2} - \frac{(a)(a-1)}{2}$

I later arrived at this formula:

$\sum\limits_{a}^n r = \frac{(n+a)(x)}{2}$

N.B. $x$ here denotes the number in the series that the last term is, rather than its value (e.g. 3rd, 4th etc.)

I however, up until now, have not found a way to make these formulae equal, even by attempting to substitute values for $a$ and $n$. Does anybody have a way to do this?

Comment: you asked if $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}-\frac{a(a+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+a)n}{2}$?

Comment: They are not equal. In the second way, the number of terms is not $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have amended it thanks for pointing that out - before I was only working with series with the value of $a$ equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The second expression, $(n+a)n/2$, is not even an integer if you start with $a$ even and $n$ odd.

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments you most probably have not properly counted the number of terms from $a$ to $n$, which is $n-a+1$. So:

$$ \sum_{r=a}^n r = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{r=a}^n r + \sum_{r=a}^n (n+a-r)\right)  $$
$$  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r=a}^n (n+a) = \frac{1}{2} (n+a) \left(\sum_{r=a}^n 1\right) $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} (n+a)(n-a+1).$$

**Edit2:** Your original proof was: 
$$ \sum_{r=a}^n r = \sum_{r=1}^n r - \sum_{r=1}^{a-1} r$$
$$ = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{(a-1)a}{2}$$
This is equal to the above expression as follows:
$$ = \frac{n+n^2}{2} - \frac{(a-1)a}{2} $$
$$ = \frac{n+n^2-a^2+a}{2} = \frac{n+a + (n+a)(n-a)}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{(n+a)(n-a+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: I just noticed thanks! The $n$ outside the brackets should really be $x$ where $x$ denotes the number in the series that the last term is, rather than its value... I've amended it. This is simply the normal formula for the summation of an arithmetic sequence, and I believe it will always be a whole number integer if the difference between each term is a whole number... By the way do you have any algebraic proof or insight as to why the sum of an arithmetic sequence using this is equation is always whole if the difference is also whole?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking why is $ \frac{1}{2} (n+a)(n-a+1)$ always an integer (whole)?

Comment: Yes - that is it.

Comment: Basically, you can think of all combinations: ($a$ odd and $n$ even),  ($a$ odd and $n$ odd) etc., and note that always one of the numbers $n+a$ or $n-a+1$ will turn out even, so their product is always even (multiple of 2).

Comment: OK thanks - that explanation makes sense now! Can you explain your proof in the answer you have given above though? I'm not really sure what you've done?

Comment: Sure. Say $a=2$ and $n=5$: $2+3+4+5=1/2*((2+3+4+5)+(5+4+3+2))$ $=1/2*((2+5)+(3+4)+(4+3)+(5+2)) = 1/2(7+7+7+7)=1/2*7*4$.

Comment: What I wrote is then exactly the same as above but with summation operator language: $2+3+4+5=\sum_{r=2}^5 r$ and $5+4+3+2=\sum_{r=2}^5 (5+2 -r) = \sum_{r=2}^5 (7 -r)$.

Comment: I do not really understand how you did this:
$$  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r=a}^n (n+a) = \frac{1}{2} (n+a) \left(\sum_{r=a}^n 1\right) $$
It seems as though you took out a factor, which I thought was not allowed?
Most of all, can you explain:
$$ n + a - r $$

Comment: Yes, $n+a$ does not depend on $r$, so it can be factored out. For the second question, as $r$ runs over $2,3,4,5$, $7-r$ runs over $5,4,3,2$. So, as $r$ runs over $a,a+1,\ldots,n-1,n$, then $n+a-r$ runs over $n,n-1,\ldots,a+1,a$. The sum of the terms doesn't change, but we run over the terms in two different ways: forwards and backwards.

Comment: @Resquiens If you're comfortable with this answer, you may want to check it (upper left corner) as accepted. Accepting an answer is relevant for this website performance statistics.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry, but I'm not sure that that answered the question I was asking. It's actually a really good proof which I hadn't thought about, but what I was wondering was how you could prove that the equations in my question could be made to be equal? I hope you can help out further? From what I understand your answer is a summation-format proof of the sum of an arithmetic series.

Comment: @Resquiens I added one more edit, Edit2, in the answer text, showing the equality of the two expressions, your original one and the one I added. Hope it helps.